# Best way to upload files in Rails5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing simple website and I have a problem with uploading files from user to server.
I've found some answers from google. But I don't know what is the best way to do that.
Could you please tell me answers or urls that presents the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Active Storage to upload image.
You can find your answers here:

> https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

This guide covers how to attach files to your Active Record models.

Comment: Thanks I had tried with that guide before but I hadn't succeed.
After you offer the guide to me and I tried again. Then I found the true answer.
You are the good dev!

Comment: Your question is related in rails and I'm always interested in such questions and news like yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can find answers from here:
https://hackernotes.io/file-uploads-rails-5-2-activestorage/
I have uploaded file using the answers and I've succeeded

Comment: You should provide context for links.
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer